# Retrieving user with same region using stored procedures in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my sample data

```
create table #t(id int identity(1,1),name varchar(10),region varchar(10),amt int)

insert into #t values('abc','R1',100),('xyz','R1',200),('lmn','R2',300),
('stu','R3',500)

create procedure test 
as @enter varchar(10)

as 
begin

select a.name,a.region,a.id from #t a join #b where a.region=b.region

end

exec test @enter='abc'
```

sample output from above should be

```
abc','R1',100
'xyz','R1',200
```

because `abc,xyz` belongs to the same Region `R1`

I am trying to execute a `SP`

which inputs the @name parameter and outputs the records which have same regions

** i am trying to get the user data that belong to same region.

but the above query isnt working.

Comment: [My fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21495)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name,a.region,a.id from #t a join #b where a.region=b.region and a.region = @enter
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subselect, if you want to create a procedure you will have to work with persistent tables.

```
Select * from #t where region=(Select region from #t sub where sub.name=@enter)
```

which could look like:

```
create table t(id int identity(1,1),name varchar(10),region varchar(10),amt int)

insert into t values('abc','R1',100),('xyz','R1',200),('lmn','R2',300),
('stu','R3',500)

GO

create procedure test ( @enter varchar(10)) as
begin

Select * from t where region=(Select region from t sub where sub.name=@enter)

end
GO

exec test @enter='abc'
```